# Deploying Web2py to Heroku (Psycopg2 Error)

Tags: postgresql, heroku, deployment, web2py, psycopg2

I'm trying to deploy a web2py app on heroku and although it works fine on my local server, I keep getting the same ticket when I deploy it.
I'm stuck on it for a few time now, trying this and that solution from several forums. 
Any help please!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/app/gluon/restricted.py", line 217, in restricted
  exec ccode in environment
 File "/app/applications/processos/models/db.py", line 21, in <module>
  db = get_db(name=None, pool_size=10)
 File "/app/gluon/contrib/heroku.py", line 25, in get_db
  db = DAL(os.environ[name], pool_size=pool_size)
 File "/app/gluon/dal.py", line 7787, in __init__
  raise RuntimeError("Failure to connect, tried %d times:\n%s" % (attempts, tb))
RuntimeError: Failure to connect, tried 5 times:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/app/gluon/dal.py", line 7766, in __init__
  self._adapter = ADAPTERS[self._dbname](**kwargs)
 File "/app/gluon/dal.py", line 2756, in __init__
  if do_connect: self.find_driver(adapter_args,uri)
 File "/app/gluon/dal.py", line 795, in find_driver
  raise RuntimeError("no driver available %s" % str(self.drivers))
RuntimeError: no driver available ('psycopg2',)
```

I'm running on a Mac OSX 10.9.2

Answer (score 2):

You need to be using virtualenv with pip for your project. Before you deploy, you need to do a `pip freeze > requirements.txt` in your projects root folder.  Heroku looks for this file and will install your requirements, accordingly.  Heroku's documentation is generally pretty good. Please refer to [Getting started with python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python) for more help.

Comment: Tks man! I fiddled a bit around the requirements.txt and it worked. Well I ran into a new problem. But this one I solved! Tks!